# How can you get paid to do research when you are retired in the UK?

Tags: job, united-kingdom

I am retired but still actively publishing.  I would, hopefully understandably, like to be paid to do this research.  Is there some way to get a grant to pay you a salary in this situation?  I don't believe a UK university will hire someone my age as a full-time employee.

One option is to become someone's postdoc but this doesn't seem ideal given the way the postdocs are managed by universities these days.

> Is there another option?

Comment: Don't you receive a pension?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Your pension is earned through the work you do up to the point of retirement. It's not payment for extra work you do after you retire!

Comment: @marshall I know what pensions are, thank you. OP is pretty much in a golden position: guaranteed income independently of how much research is produced, no boss, complete freedom in what they can research, no bureaucracy, no teaching... It's basically what all academics aspire to. The only "issue" appears to be that the income is not given as a reward for the work produced. (If the pension is not enough to live on, then OP is not retired, OP is actually unemployed. It's a bit sad that it can get to this point in a civilized society, though.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't understand this line of thinking.  To me it's the same as saying that anyone who already has enough money for food and shelter should work for free.  Sure you can choose to do that but I don't see why it is necessarily the right thing to do. The age you are when doing the work seems irrelevant, at least to me. (Also, at least in the UK, your pension is very unlikely to give you a luxurious lifestyle.)

Comment: @marshall *To me it's the same as saying that anyone who already has enough money for food and shelter should work for free* No, that's not what I'm saying, at all. But honestly, past experience has shown that discussing politics online is pointless, so I'll stop here.

Comment: I guess you (the OP) are looking for soft money sources in the UK where you have a higher status than postdoc. An interesting question.

Comment: It might help to clarify the position you are retired from. I interpret your question to mean that you were not a professor, so you are not emeritus or otherwise could be considered associated with an academic institution (where you might get certain types of grants). Is that correct?

Comment: @JonCuster Grants in the UK typically don't pay a salary to the PI. The only people who get money are usually the postdocs. Also there is typically a requirement to be in permanent employment to be a PI. I haven't heard of this including retired emeritus professors but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Lembik - Good to know - I'm not familiar with the UK system. How strict is the limitation to postdocs? Or, how are grad students funded? Can a consultant be brought onto a project? Collaborators?

Comment: @lembik really? I work for the major funder of applied health research in the U.K. and we most certainly do pay for PI time. I think your statement must be discipline or funder specific.

Comment: @rhialto I was thinking of RCUK grants (e.g. EPSRC).  Can you say which fund you work for.

Comment: @rhialto Just to clarify, do you mean the PI gets an increased salary paid directly into their bank account or that the university they work for gets a percentage of their normal salary from the funder but the PIs salary is unaffected?

Comment: @Lembik the second - the money to pay for the investigator time goes to the lead contracting institution (often but not always a university) which then distributes it to other institutions. They then use it to pay their staff.

Comment: @Lembik NIHR, but there are definitely schemes within RCUK which pay for investigator time - see for example this guide from the MRC which sets out how to put these costs into the application. Which makes me think not paying for investigators must be discipline specific, it’s certainly not a generic trait of funders in the U.K.

Comment: @rhialto We may be talking at slight cross purposes. In the US you get a salary if you have the right grant for the three months in the Summer and you don’t otherwise.  In Israel you can get part of a grant paid directly to you as a salary bonus.   That’s the sort of thing I am referring to.

Comment: @rhialto (Is the link missing in "this guide"?) The difference is that in one case you are poorer if you don't get the grant and in the other it makes no difference to how much money you have.   "pay for PI time" versus "pay the PI for their time".

Comment: @JonCuster At least for the major math, CS and physical science funder you can’t pay for grad students from a grant. The university gets some funding you can apply for or you have to look for an established doctoral training program or other funding sources. I don’t know the answer in relation to one off consultancy fees though.

Answer (score 2):

Establish yourself as a freelance expert consultant (plenty of online advice to do this), and find the right clients interested in funding your research.